# Installation Failure: No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\ahg\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\7zOF48A.tmp\\wubi.exe'

Tags: system-installation

This is the last line in the log file:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   'C:\Users\ahg\AppData\Local\Temp\7zOF48A.tmp\wubi.exe'

Answer (score 2):

Wubi is deprecated as it causes no end of problems.  Please use *any other installation method **except** wubi*!  Please?  Pretty please???

- [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)
- [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)
- [Official installation documentation](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop)